# How do I edit the top link nav bar in Sharepoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online

There is a top level nav bar on our Sharepoint Online intranet site that I cannot seem to edit in any of the menus that I have found. Can anyone offer some advice on how I might remove these links? Unfortunately the developer was a contractor who is long gone and we have no internal support for Sharepoint so I am stuck with dead links that need to be removed.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about the links (locations, about us etc) , they can be modified easily. They must be coming from either Managed navigation or Structural navigation. You can find it by navigating to site settings-> Navigation(Under look and feel)-->Global Navigation settings. If it is marked as Managed navigation, then you should head to the term store management, site settings--> term store management(under Site administration). If it is marked as Structural navigation, then you can choose one from the available options.

If the Global Navigation settings link is missing from the admin page, you can go directly to the admin url: /_layouts/15/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx

If you are talking about the Icon like links(Employee hub,Social etc), then the master page should be holding these. You can modify/remove these by editing the html version of the master page.

Comment: I just wanted to say that I came here from Google and your answer was extremely helpful. Thank you.